# Use tablet screen as touch screen monitor

Tags: hdmi, tablet, touchscreen

Is there any way to use an old tablet screen as a touch screen monitor for pc?

I know it's possible to use it as a normal monitor with a controller board but I have no clue on how to do use the touch screen. Convert it to usb like normal touch screen monitors out there in the market that use both hdmi (or vga, dp, whatever) and a usb for the input.

Comment: Android tablet or iPad?

Comment: Preferably Android tablet, but if iPad is the only option, it can do too

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this app but it appears to do what you want:

**iDisplay**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen&hl=en